# import win32com.client

Tags: python, library

Коллеги, никак не работает библиотека pywin32:

```
 import win32com.client 
 Excel=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
 wb=Excel.Workbooks.Open(u'C:\\Users\\Farrukh\\Desktop\\test.xlsx')
```

Ответ: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
Уже пытался через командную строку "python -m pip install pypiwin32, python -m pip install pywin32 и pip install pywin32." Не помогает

Comment: https://qastack.ru/superuser/609447/how-to-install-the-win32com-python-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно скачать [отсюда](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/#files) для своей версии Python и так же через pip install "путь к файлу" установить.

Comment: Спасибо! А как определить какая версия соответствует моему установленному питону. У Меня Python3.8(32бит). И потом как установить через CMD: pip install pywin32XXXXXXX и тогдали

Comment: Вот ссылка https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/6d/e47d8020c21849498d84fb9f75e4d7ab3414eebacb85fa7e1d61e34fae67/pywin32-228-cp38-cp38-win32.whl для 3.8 win32. Установка: 
pip install путь до файла\pywin32-228-cp38-cp38-win32.whl

Comment: Ответ идет таким образом ERROR: pywin32-228-......... whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Comment: Вы уверены, что python 32 битный и он установлен единственный? Попробуйте открыть консоль и прописать туда Python, он вернет версию и разрядность.

Comment: Все у меня походу с Pycharm проблемы. С питон IDE попробовал, ну дефолтный через родной. Работает

Comment: Спасибо большое!